# selectedSegmentIndex doesn't change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a UITableView with one row, inside this row I have a UISwitch with 3 segments. In my case, I need to get the selected index, with a code that select by tag:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

    UITableViewCell *cellAttachment = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell0"];

    UISegmentedControl *btnAttachment = nil;
    btnAttachment = (UISegmentedControl*)[cellAttachment viewWithTag:100];
    NSLog(@"Segment -> %ld",(long)btnAttachment.selectedSegmentIndex);
}
```

With this code, I can get the segment selected, but when I try to change the segment with:

```
btnAttachment.selectedSegmentIndex = [self.arrayFields[19] intValue];//Inside this array has a number 1!
```

Nothing is done, whats the problem? (I'm doing without a IBOutlet, is possible?)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without IBOutlet. You just have to add action handler from code (in viewDidLoad):

```
[btnAttachment addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

then add action method:

```
-(void)segmentedControlDidChange:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
NSLog(@"Segment -> %ld",(long) sender.selectedSegmentIndex);
}
```

Comment: Great, but I don't need to get the selectedIndex when user click, I need to change the SelectedIndex programatically..

Comment: Oh, I get it. Action method doesn't get call when you set `selectedSegmentIndex` programatically. This is desired and common behaviour in UI controls. 2 solutions: subclass UISegmentedControl or call `[btnAttachment sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];` manually after setting `selectedSegmentIndex`.